# Crystal Reports 2013,NULL Need to Account for NULL values in UNIX timestamp. Using DateAdd function

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am using Crystal Reports 2013 and I have several fields that have a UNIX timestamp that I need to convert to a date field.  I am using a DataAdd function that works well as long as there is a timestamp in the field.  However,  when the timestamp field is NULL the Crystal Report crashes.  What needs to be changed in the coded to account for NULL values?  Here is my code.

DateAdd("s",{GEO_NSS_FEMA_NSS_open_csv.SHELTER_CLOSED_DATE}/1000, #1/1/1970 00:00:00#)

Thank you.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Replace: `{field}`

With: `If isnull({field}) then 0 else {field}`